# C: Creating a file in a directory not owned by the current user, Windows

Tags: c, windows

I recently created a program (originally for linux) that requires the ability to create files so it can save data. It creates a directory that contains the files if needed. This works fine on linux and mac, however on *some* windows setups, it does not. I tested on a fresh 64-bit Windows 10 virtual machine and everything works fine (ie, `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fread` work fine), but when tested on a computer that has had windows for a few years, it creates no files. The directory is created without a problem though.

I believe the problem is the same as the one explained here https://superuser.com/questions/846143/remove-read-only-attribute-from-folder-after-windows-reinstall

That is, that the NTFS filesystem (and therefore all the directories in it) is not owned by the user attempting to run my program. This is attributed to the windows installation that created the filesystem not being the same installation that is now trying to run my program. Another description of the issue is that right clicking on a directory, going to **Properties** and attempting to uncheck Read Only is possible, but upon rechecking, it has made itself Read Only again. It's worth noting that the Read Only checkbox isn't checked, but filled with a square, rather.

My program also has a java component to it that makes use of BufferedWriter. This seems to be unaffected by this issue and can create files no problem, so it must be possible to circumnavigate this problem, I just don't know how to do that in C. And that's my question, **how do I create files (Using C) on a Windows installation affected by this problem?**

Code that I have tried that didn't work on the bugged windows installs:

```
HANDLE test = CreateFile(file_path, GENERIC_WRITE,
    0, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
WriteFile(test, "file created", sizeof("file created"), NULL, NULL);
CloseHandle(test);
```

and not using the windows API:

```
/* Open file for appending */
FILE *f = fopen(file_path, "ab+");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    return -1;
}
int len_s = strlen(s);
/* Write the length of s to the file */
if (1 != fwrite(&len_s, sizeof(char), 1, f)) return -2;
fclose(f);
```

Neither of these create the files let alone write the content on the bugged windows install. It's worth noting the `fopen` code block is what works on linux, mac, and the windows 10 virtual machine I tested on, and the `CreateFile` block works on the virtual machine.

Comment: What is the error you get from CreateFile?

Comment: It could help to clarify the problem if you show the output from `icacls directory_path`. I can tell you it certainly has nothing to do with the read-only attribute on the directory, which probably isn't even set. Unlike the Linux "immutable" file attribute, setting a directory as "read only" in Windows only prevents the directory from being deleted; it has nothing to do with whether you can add or remove files.

Comment: I had to find another computer with the issue as I lost access to the first. Okay so as for the error from CreateFile, I added `perror("CreateFile");` after the `CloseHandle(Test);` line and that causes the program to crash with a message from windows "...has encountered a problem and needs to close".

Comment: The computer I'm testing on now is running Windows XP and it says "'icacls' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

Comment: Also, on this computer, it creates the files using this code:
    HANDLE f = CreateFile(file_path, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    WriteFile(f, "", sizeof(""), NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(f);

Comment: Testing my program on 32 bit windows XP, it's working close to perfectly, sometimes it fails to access files because of permission issues when there are multiple accesses in quick succession, but re-running the command usually solves that. I believe what changed is I included <windows.h> and <io.h> in the program files. As for CreateFile, in the code I mentioned in my previous comment, it was crashing after the WriteFile call and I was unable to find out why. `fopen` was working by this time though so I removed that code. Thanks trying to help; sorry I couldn't get answers to your questions!

Comment: `perror` has nothing to do with the Windows API. If `CreateFile` fails, the result is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, in which case `GetLastError` returns the Windows error code.

Comment: In XP use cacls.exe instead of icacls.exe.